# Need Old Version of plugins

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I updated plugin by mistake. it mess the design of website. How I can revert old version of plugins? how I can be sure which version I was using before?

Thank you

Comment: This is why you always make backups of your data and files before attempting an update, so you can revert your changes if anything goes bad. Since there is no way to see what versions you were using after the update has been performed, you need to rely on data you have stored of it (either on paper, or on a digital backup). There is no way you can find it in your WordPress install anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for old versions of a plugin in the WordPress repository (like WooCommerce), you can go to the plugin's page on WordPress.org/plugins, then look in the right column under the plugin's Tags for the link to "Advanced View". Click on that, then scroll all the way down and select from the dropdown under Previous Versions to download an earlier version. This is that screen for WooCommerce: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/advanced/

After downloading the older version of the plugin, go to your WordPress control panel > Plugins screen and click "Add New", the click the "Upload Plugin" button. Select the older version's file, upload it, click "Install" and then "Activate". (If you get a message at this point that the plugin cannot be installed because the directory already exists, you may have to deactivate the current plugin and uninstall/delete it before uploading the older version again. Make sure to make a backup of your site before you do this).

As far as determining what version you were using previously, I'm not sure how you'd determine that after updating. You may have to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

The following plugin is the solution you're looking for : [WP Rollback](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rollback/). It allows you to retrieve any anterior version of any plugin or theme activated on your administration.

Of course, before to do anything, **you should save all your files and database** just in case something bad happens. Hope it helps.

1. Install WP Rollback from the catalog.
2. Activate it in your dashboard.
3. Then go on **Dashboard > Plugins > Installed Plugins** : here you can choose, for all the plugins or themes activated, any anterior version. You just have to click on WP Rollback. You will even keep your settings.
4. To find precisely the version of the plugin you were using, just try with the previous version and check if it solves your design issue. If not, try again with the previous version, and so on until you find the one that is not breaking your design.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps helps me download any version of the plugin

1. Go to plugin page on WordPress site ex: https://wordpress.org/plugins/download-manager/
2. Open any plugin screenshot/image. It will open link straight to image ex: https://ps.w.org/file-manager-advanced/assets/screenshot-1.png?rev=1821394
3. Change above URL and go to 1 folder before assets which will allow you to browse directory, go to tags folder (ex: https://ps.w.org/download-manager/tags/).
4. From there you will be able to see and download any version of the plugin.

Only works for plugins that are in WP store.